# burned image file ubutu 12.4.2 for Amd64 iso to CD but it won't boot

Tags: boot

I have a new computer without OS. I want to try Ubuntu before putting anything else on it. 
AMD Athlon II Biostar A780L3C. Each time I try to boot with the CD. I get a Purple screen with an Icon of a Control Screen = a figure of a man then It goes black with a curser blinking at the upper right hand corner. I have to reboot as no other imput from the keyboard is accepted.

Comment: Please try again, and give your computer more time. CDs are very slow to load up, and consequently, it's a much better idea to use a usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

While boot up press f2 or f12. Change boot priority to external drive/USB. Boot through USB and install. It's more reliable and fast.Here easy step to follow [UNETBOOTIN](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Hoppe it help.